# Should I get a second graphics card to have a dual monitor setup?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, vga, dvi

I bought a second monitor for my desktop computer. While setting it up, I realized it only has 1 VGA slot connected to my graphics card.

There is one extra VGA and DVI slot at the back of the case, but they are not connected to anything. And when I connect my new monitor to either one of them it does not work ("no input").

My first question is: can I just get a VGA splitter and solve this problem?I want an extended display with dual monitors.

Or, should I buy a second graphics card? Is there any other way that I don't know?

These are my system specs:

```
Operating System: Windows 7 Professional 32-bit SP1
CPU: AMD A6-3600 Llano 32nm Technology
RAM: 4GB DDR3 @ 666MHz (9-9-9-24)
Motherboard: ASUSTeK Computer INC. CM1740 (FM1 )    
Graphics: PHL 243V5 (1920x1080@60Hz) 1024MB ATI AMD Radeon HD 7400M Series (ASUStek)    
Storage: 931 GB Seagate ST31000524AS ATA Device (SATA)
Optical Drives: ATAPI DVD A DH24ABS ATA Device
Audio: AMD High Definition Audio Device
```

Comment: Please provide a photo of your PC’s back side and indicate where the currently working display is usually connected. No, a VGA splitter won’t work. Also, why use VGA at all? It sucks.

Comment: [This](http://imgur.com/KjPwupk) is back of my computer. In the red paint there is my graphics card and its VGA slot is located. Only the VGA on that red part works. I don't know, I am a complete noob at this stuff.

Comment: I assume you downloaded that image, as opposed to taking an actual picture of your case.  I assume this, because I don't see VGA (or even a graphics card) where the red circled part is.  If this is the case, then the photo doesn't really help.  The VGA and DVI visible higher up are not connected to "nothing" as you stipulated, they should be connected to an onboard graphics chip, which simply means you can't run on both connectors (above and below) simultaneously, as you cannot use on- and off-board graphics at the same time.

Comment: @Hitsugaya198 I understand your explanation. But I don't know what should I do to solve it.

Comment: You CAN turn on both on-board and off-board graphics at the same time but you need to read your system manual to find out how.

Comment: @hulegukhaan If you only have an onboard graphics card and no other, you should try plugging one display into DVI and the other into VGA (the two connectors attached to the motherboard).  If you have an external PCIe or AGP graphics card with only one connector, you could disable or remove it and try the onboard graphics card, or if you want to use the GPU at any point for some hard work like gaming or graphic rendering, I suggest you buy a new card that supports dual monitors.

Answer (score 1):

No need for second gfx card. 
You need to be sure to enable the correct output mode on your Ati Control Panel

[image]

Comment: Either I read the question wrong, or you did, because to me, it seems like there is only a single connector available on the graphics card, making it physically impossible to connect the second screen.  If this is the case, how will configuring his output mode in Ati Control Panel in any way solve the problem @user2818782?

Comment: My catalyst was not working so I am reinstalling. Thank you.

Comment: When I open it it only detects my current monitor.

Comment: @Hitsugaya198 He has an AMD APU, a CPU with integrated Radeon Graphics. But there’s no need to use the CCC, because the Windows display settings applet can also manage that.

Comment: I would have asked that as a comment but reputation etc..
Bottom line: if there's only one port, you can only have one (non-mirrored) monitor. So perhaps then a gfx card is in order so that OP may join the glorious master race gaming community.

Comment: @user2818782 - You should avoid submitting answers before you get the clarification you need to submit an answer.  Your single sentence is incomplete, if he only has a single VGA connection, then that limits his options.